# Unity3D - Не отображаются спрайты при запуске проекта

Tags: unity3d, спрайт

Я относительно недавно начал изучать Unity3D, делаю свой первый проект, и при запуске лвлов, обнаружил, что на некоторых не отображаются спрайты, хотя ходить по ним можно. Вот скриншоты: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUnEu.jpg . Из-за чего это может быть, и как это исправить? За ранее рад помощи.

Comment: Альфа канал глянь, слой камеры которую она видит и слой спрайтов, ну и Z координату можно

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего z позиция объектов находится за камерой. Попробуй выставить у всех исчезнувших спрайтов transform.possition.z=0